# How to stop a cell's content from being used to calculate column width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with a dynamic width, and with each column being a dynamic portion of that width, depending on cell contents.

In the headers of that table, I have an input set to 100% width, which is initially hidden. When triggered, the input appears.  Unfortunately, if the column's cell's contents are quite narrow, the column widths are then recalculated and the width jumps.

How do I set the input to just fill up the cell's width & not push it wider?

**I don't believe there is a solution, but I thought I'd ask the larger community before giving up. My guess is I can't without hard-coding widths, but that's out of the question.**

***Edit:*** My solution has been to let the browser do the cell width calculations, then using Javascript, explicitly set the column widths to whatever was calculated.  This allows the cell contents to determine the width, but I still get set-width behaviour.

```js
function toggleInput(){
  var target = document.querySelector('.hidden')
  var newStyle = (target.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
  document.querySelector('.hidden').style.display = newStyle;
}

document.querySelector('th').addEventListener('click',toggleInput);
```

```css
table,td,th{
  border:1px solid red;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

table,
input{
  width:100%;
}

.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Click me
        <div class="hidden">
          <input />
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
      </th>
      <th>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Blah
      </td>
      <td>
        Some longer text to stretch
      </td>
      <td>
        More text
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you can manually set the column's width in the TH.

Comment: **My guess is I can't without hard-coding widths, but that's out of the question.**

Answer (score 0):

By using the following CSS:

```
table { table-layout:fixed }
```

Your code with the fix:

```js
function toggleInput(){
  var target = document.querySelector('.hidden')
  var newStyle = (target.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
  document.querySelector('.hidden').style.display = newStyle;
}

document.querySelector('th').addEventListener('click',toggleInput);
```

```css
table,td,th{
  border:1px solid red;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

table,
input{
  width:100%;
}

table { table-layout:fixed; }

.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Click me
        <div class="hidden">
          <input />
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
      </th>
      <th>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Blah
      </td>
      <td>
        Some longer text to stretch
      </td>
      <td>
        More text
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not quite.  From MDN: "Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths."  I need the column with to be determined by each column's contents.

Comment: @Pickle - then it's not possible without setting fixed widths.